# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

I'm having some weird problem right now.
So apparently, there have been problems with my MySQL PDO drivers, as well as with my Apache server, so I had it reinstalled.
But now, this parse error suddenly appeared after I had done that:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 5
```

Well, this is the code on line 5:

```
return array_map(function ($val) { return explode('.', $val)[0]; }, scandir(DIR . M_DIR));
```

I seriously don't get this. And it seems like no matter what I try to do in order to fix this error -- it remains effective.
Help?

Answer (score 2):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

[array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

So take a look on [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88)

Your code must be looks that for

```
return array_map(
    function ($val)
        { 
        $temp = explode('.', $val); 
        return $temp[0]; 
        }, 
    scandir(DIR . M_DIR));
```

or

```
return array_map(
    function ($val)
        { 
        return current(explode('.', $val));
        }, 
    scandir(DIR . M_DIR));
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the exploded array in another variable and then return the 0th index.

Like this:

```
return array_map( function ($val) { 
        $temp explode('.', $val);
        return $temp[0];
    }, scandir(DIR . M_DIR));
```